# ServiceStack OrmLite: Use default database constraint instead of null value from data model

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm still pretty new to these technologies. I've run into a small issue, and it's one that can be fixed by writing some lazy code...but OrmLite and ServiceStack streamline so many things, I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

So, I have a data model:

```
public class cctv_camera
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int I_id { get; set; }
    public string I_sid { get; set; }
    public string C_store_id { get; set; }
    // .... others
}
```

This data model is mapped to a table, cctv_camera. There's another model (call it CamDetail) being sent to the client after some joins from this table. We are receiving back a CamDetail object from the client on a POST to save to the database and populating an instance of `lp_cctv_camera` with the data (`new lp_cctv_camera().PopulateWith(CamDetail);`).

Here's the thing: the `I_sid` column is a NOT NULL column with a default constraint that generates a hash for that row. It's something that the database is responsible for, so new items should not `INSERT` this column; it should be generated by the constraint.

Is there any way to `db.Insert(lp_cctv_camera)` while ignoring this column? I have tried the `[Ignore]` attribute on the definition, but we still need it in the definition to send existing `I_sid`s out to the client. I really can't find anything in the docs. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've added an explicit `[IgnoreOnInsert]` attribute you can use to ignore specific properties on Insert which is [available on v4.5.13 on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Prior to v4.5.13 you can use the `[Compute]` attribute to get the similar behavior and ignore fields during inserts, e.g:

```
public class cctv_camera
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int I_id { get; set; }
    [Compute]
    public string I_sid { get; set; }
    public string C_store_id { get; set; }
    // .... others
}
```

Comment: mythz to the rescue again. Thanks so much!